# apscheduler loses a job after reboot

Tags: redis, python-3.7, apscheduler

I've faced a problem with python APScheduler.
I've made a simple script:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler({
    'apscheduler.jobstores.default': {
        'type': 'redis',
        'host': "127.0.0.1",
        'port': 6379,
        'db': 0,
        'encoding': "utf-8",
        'encoding_errors': "strict",
        'decode_responses': False,
        'retry_on_timeout': False,
        'ssl': False,
        'ssl_cert_reqs': "required"
    },
    'apscheduler.executors.default': {
        'class': 'apscheduler.executors.pool:ThreadPoolExecutor',
        'max_workers': '20'
    },
    'apscheduler.job_defaults.coalesce': 'false',
    'apscheduler.job_defaults.max_instances': '3',
    'apscheduler.timezone': 'UTC',
}, daemon=False)
scheduler.start()

def testfunc():
    with open('./data.log', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{datetime.now()}\n')

scheduler.add_job(testfunc, 'interval', minutes=1, id='my_job_id')
scheduler.add_job(testfunc, 'date', run_date="2120-1-1 11:12:13", id='my_job_id_2')

while True:
    scheduler.print_jobs()
    sleep(10)
```

So, I'm using BackgroundScheduler with ThreadPoolExecutor and Redis jobstore, quite simple, as in documentation.

It's working fine, tasks added, I can see data in redis-cli also.
Then I reboot server and check data in redis again. And what I see is only **my_job_id_2** task. The one with **interval** trigger disappeared totally.
Redis is set to save data to RDB every minute. The same happening if I execute SAVE command in redis-cli before reboot.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's saving?

1. check the configuration

```
redis-cli config get save
1) "save"
2) "3600 1 300 100 60 10000"
```

2. check the redis log to ensure the save has occured

```
1:M 16 Sep 2021 16:06:31.375 * DB saved on disk
```

example w/ error

```
547130:M 16 Sep 2021 09:12:58.100 # Error moving temp DB file temp-547130.rdb on the final destination dump.rdb (in server root dir /home/namizaru/redis/src): Operation not permitted
```

3. Make sure on restart it's loading the file in the redis log

```
549156:M 16 Sep 2021 09:14:31.522 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
```

4. consider using AOF as it logs all of the commands so you'll at least be able to figure out which commands are getting missed

Answer (score 0):

Redis is an in-memory store unless you configure persistence data will be dropped between reboots.

https://redis.io/topics/persistence details the options available to you

Comment: As I said in the question,` Redis is set to save data to RDB every minute. `. So, it persists data